# Swift Custom Map Callout - Resize for each device

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, callout

This isn't a coding question, more of in need of which way to go. I created a custom call out but the problem is that it doesn't resize to the devices. Some devices it fits perfect and others it completely zoomed in on. Will using the stack view method help with this size problem? Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Depends on how you are setting up your layout. Are you using Auto Layout ?

Comment: Yes, I am using a xib file too

Comment: nathan if you could help me on this it would mean a lot since I cannot find any information about this problem